# What is the best way to write two enum classes containing common functionality

Tags: java, enums

```
public class Class1{
    public enum Enum1 {
        A("title") {
            public void process(SomeClass a) {
                String value = a.getTitle();
            }
        }, B("name") {
            public void process(SomeClass b) {
                String value = b.getName();
            }
        }

public class Class2{
    public enum Enum2 {
        A("title") {
            public void process(SomeClass a) {
                String value = a.getTitle();
            }
        }, C("desc") {
           public void process(SomeClass b) {
               String value = b.getDesc();
           }
        }
```

Class1 and Class2 having the enum A as common.
How can i make the two common enums to a generic one?

Comment: please reformat your code snippet using indentation and linefeeds. Additionally please clarify what you mean by "make the two common enums to a generic one"

Comment: No, you cannot. You could create an `interface` and have both `enum` implement it - that way you could use either `enum` in methods. It would help if you have a more concrete use case for this, as it seems odd.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Could you provide a sample snippet for the above case?

Comment: This really smells like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

Why not making a own enum file with content like:

```
public enum Enum {

    A {
        public void process(Object b) {
            //Do something
        }
    },
    B {
        public void process(Object b) {
            //Do something
        }
    },
    C {
        public void process(Object b) {
            //Do something
        }
    };

    public void process(Object b) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

This enum you can import in your other classes and use very simply:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Enum a = Enum.A;
        a.process("123");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this code snap shot? Are you looking for this?

```
public class Component {

    private String name;
    private String title;

    public Component(String name, String title) {
        this.name = name;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1(FieldsEnum.NAME);
        class1.process();

        Class2 class2 = new Class2(FieldsEnum.TITLE);
        class2.process();
    }
}

enum FieldsEnum {
    TITLE {
        public void process(Component component) {
            System.out.println("Process with : " + component.getTitle());
        }
    },
    NAME {
        public void process(Component component) {
            System.out.println("Process with : " + component.getName());
        }
    };

    public abstract void process(Component component);
}

class Base {
    public Base(FieldsEnum field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    private FieldsEnum field;

    public FieldsEnum getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(FieldsEnum field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public void process() {
        this.field.process(new Component("HomePage", "HomeTitle"));
    }
}

class Class1 extends Base {
    public Class1(FieldsEnum field) {
        super(field);
    }

    // do you class1 specific work here
}

class Class2 extends Base {

    public Class2(FieldsEnum field) {
        super(field);
    }

    // do you class2 specific work here
}
```